# Is there a way to have superscript characters in og:description?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Doe anyone know of a way to have superscript characters in your og:description meta data for Facebook shares?

The problem I face is I need to include the registered symbol in superscript next to a product name in our og:description. If you use html  tag it breaks it and shows nothing.

I know it's unicode and unicode seems to have only superscript numbers not for registered trademark and copyright symbols.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use characters like x² x₈ © ™?

I made a quick test and seems to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.quanticosoft.com/test/testog.html" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />

    <meta property="og:description" content="Using a unicode superscripts characters: x² x₈ © ™ " />
</head>
<body>
    Using a unicode superscripts characters: x² x₈ © ™
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using the facebook debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object

On the output I can correctly see my characters. On the raw section I see:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Using unicode superscripts characters: x&#xb2; x&#x2088; " />
```

Of course I saved the page using UTF-8 encoding and added the meta charset utf-8.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, unicode has specific characters for superscript and subscript numbers but not registered, copyright and trademark. So thanks for the example but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Richard Ok, but maybe your title is a little confused... Anyway I tried using © ™ symbols and seems to work as usual. Here my test page: http://www.quanticosoft.com/test/testog.html .